# ImportError: libsingular-Singular-4.3.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, sage

I am trying to run `sage` in the Ubuntu 23.10 terminal and it throws this exact error: `ImportError: libsingular-Singular-4.3.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I am not sure which package to install and (considering the new ubuntu 23 (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465218/pip-error-on-ubuntu-externally-managed-environment-%C3%97-this-environment-is-extern) thing) how.

if it matters, I installed sage from apt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug:

A quick workaround is downgrading singular-related packages. Here is a one-line-solution:

```
curl -O https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/singular/libsingular4-dev-common_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_all.deb -O https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/singular/libsingular4-dev_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb -O https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/singular/libsingular4m3n0_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb -O https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/singular/singular-data_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_all.deb -O https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/singular/singular-modules_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb -O https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/singular/singular-ui_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb -O https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/singular/singular_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i libsingular4-dev-common_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_all.deb libsingular4-dev_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb libsingular4m3n0_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb singular-data_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_all.deb singular-modules_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb singular-ui_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb singular_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb && sudo apt-mark hold libsingular4-dev-common libsingular4-dev libsingular4m3n0 singular-data singular-modules singular-ui singular && rm -f libsingular4-dev-common_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_all.deb libsingular4-dev_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb libsingular4m3n0_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb singular-data_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_all.deb singular-modules_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb singular-ui_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb singular_4.3.1-p3+ds-1_amd64.deb
```

Complete answer on git: https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/36688